# Reference a figure in a letter

Tags: labels, letters, includegraphics, pageref

I want to write a letter and include a figure, here's an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{letter}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{
    To you
  }

  \opening{Dear you}

  This is what I wanted to tell you.

  \closing{Goodbye}

\end{letter}

%  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{somefigure}
%    \label{somefigure}
%  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can I reference this figure in a letter? Specifically I would like to use something like `\pageref`. Since there is no `figure` environment in `letter`, I do not know how to label and reference the figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `figure` for a page reference.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{letter}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{
    To you
  }

  \opening{Dear you}

  This is what I wanted to tell you. See the image on page~\pageref{somefigure}




  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=1.\textwidth]{example-image}
    \label{somefigure}

  \end{center}

  \closing{Goodbye}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```